# When multiple instances of an object are created, are the attached methods shared or copied?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I've been reviewing these two MDN documents on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [the object model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) in attempt of determining whether or not it would be worthwhile to modify a large set of code from a set of functions to an object with a set of methods, because I want to permit the user to create multiple instances of a large portion of the page.

The small tests I've been trying work well and it appears a good approach, but I don't quite understand what takes place with the attached methods when multiple instances of an object are created.

Following this MDN example, since the method declarations are not inside the constructor function, if three instances of `MyObject` were created, would the three instances "share" the same two methods, similar to having declared only two functions and passing the object data, or would it result in the equivalent of adding six functions to the script where each instance has identical copies of the same two functions?

Thank you.

```
function MyObject(name, message) {
  this.name = name.toString();
  this.message = message.toString();
}
MyObject.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
};
MyObject.prototype.getMessage = function() {
  return this.message;
};

object_1 = new MyObject( name_1, message_1 );
object_2 = new MyObject( name_2, message_2 );
object_3 = new MyObject( name_3, message_3 );
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS

Comment: given that "functions are first class objects", so you can check their reference equality using `===` like `object_1.getName === object_2.getName`. And check this [Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: @lastr2d2 Thanks. That's interesting; I hadn't thought of functions as having a reference before. I tried it and the result is `true`.  Does this mean that the multiple instances inherit the property names and methods, and only differ in property values? That would be preferrable and the same as declaring only one copy of inherited methods. I read a few questions that seem to say the same is true in Java classes but couldn't find confirmation in JavaScript.

Comment: it depends on how you define these properties. In your example `this.name` belongs to the instance while the `getName` belongs to the function prototype. Check the prototype chain link and you will get a better explanation

Comment: Thanks. I think I see now. `hasOwnProperty` seems to provide the same result.